# Convert dumps to proper json

Tags: python, json

The file i have

```
{'What': {'top':                          query  value
0              what time is it    100
1                what to watch     37
2                what is my ip     17
3                what the font      5
4  what dinosaur has 500 teeth      2, 'rising':                          query  value
0  what dinosaur has 500 teeth   2200
1                what to watch    150}}
```

The json i want

```
{
    "What": {
        "top": [
            {"query": "what time is it", "value": 100},
            {"query": "what to watch", "value": 37},
            {"query": "what is my ip", "value": 17},
            {"query": "what the font", "value": 5},
            {"query": "what dinosaur has 500 teeth", "value": 2}
        ],
        "rising": [
            {"query": "what dinosaur has 500 teeth", "value": 2200},
            {"query": "what to watch", "value": 150}
        ]
    }
}
```

Python Code that print json, not sure if i missed something

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import json

# Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
pytrend = TrendReq()

# Create payload and capture API tokens. Only needed for interest_over_time(), interest_by_region() & related_queries()
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['Which'], geo='US', timeframe='now 7-d')

# Get related queries data
related_queries_dict = pytrend.related_queries()

# Print the related_queries_dict
print(related_queries_dict)
```

To convert text to proper json , but thing is there is some orientation is missing i guess or do i missed to add the function?

Comment: `print(related_queries_dict)` does not give you JSON output. (it wouldn't give the output at the top of your question either, that looks totally broken...) You can use `data = json.dumps(related_queries_dict)` to get a string containing json data

Comment: @Anentropic
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Comment: ok so it's not a dict. It seems that dataframes have their own `to_json` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Per:
> https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/a9984ffdc9b31d853dde2ab614a77ecbf2bf33a1/pytrends/request.py#L429

`related_queries()` gives you a dictionary of keywords with values of a dictionary with two keys. The values of these keys are pandas Dataframes.

```py
{
    "<keyword>": {
        "rising": df_rising,
        "top": df_top
    },
}
```

You will want to iterate that dictionary and for every key word key you will want to cast the values of those to a dictionary via `pandas.to_dict()`

I.E.:

```py
import pandas

df_top = pandas.DataFrame([{"foo": "foo"},{"foo": "bar"}])
df_rising = pandas.DataFrame([{"foo": "foo"},{"foo": "bar"}])

result = {
    "What": {
        "top": df_top,
        "rising": df_rising
    }
}

for value in result.values():
    value["top"] = value["top"].to_dict(orient="records")
    value["rising"] = value["rising"].to_dict(orient="records")

import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```